# Google Sheet: How to add a string to a google query input data

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want a kind of transpose. I want a copy of different columns in new sheet with a new column included.
It should look like this:
Test!A:A,"ROW CD", Test!C:D
Test!A:A,"ROW EF", Test!E:F

This is working:
`=QUERY( { Test!A:A,Test!C:D; Test!A:A,Test!E:F } , "SELECT *", 1)`

This generates a #REF! error:
`=QUERY( { Test!A:A,"ROW CD", Test!C:D; Test!A:A,"ROW EF", Test!E:F } , "SELECT *", 1)`

How can I solve this? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(r,ROW(Test!A:A),
       QUERY({Test!A:A,IF(r,"ROW CD"),Test!C:D;
              Test!A:A,IF(r,"ROW EF"),Test!E:F}, "SELECT *",1)))
```